# How to change the timezone in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, timezone, azure-sql-database

We would like to get the date in a specific location, either by using something like the C# solution:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(DateTime.Now, "West US Time");
```

Or by setting the Azure SQL Database timezone and then using getdate().

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From MSDN: Use [`AT TIME ZONE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt612795.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 01:01:00')   
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';  
--2015-03-29 01:01:00.000 +01:00  

--Time between 02:00 and 03:00 is converted as +01!  
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 02:01:00')   
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';  
--2015-03-29 02:01:00.000 +01:00  

SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '03/29/2015 03:01:00')   
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time';  
--2015-03-29 03:01:00.000 +02:00
```

Comment: Does it really change DB machine's system time, or just show you a zone converted time ?