# Change Azure MS SQL Time zone

Tags: sql-server, azure, timezone, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure MS SQL DB (PAAS) and want to change its time zone from UTC to IST.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the SQL Server (in Azure) TimeZone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051034/how-to-change-the-sql-server-in-azure-timezone)

Comment: The bigger question is - WHY do you want to do this?  Of what meaningful purpose is your database's *local* time zone important to your use case?  Relying on the system time zone is generally a bad idea. 
 If you need the local time in a particular time zone, convert from UTC to that time zone (with `AT TIME ZONE`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the default time zone on Azure SQL DB is UTC. Unfortunately, there is **not** possible to change by server configuration or database configuration.

More information about it please refer to this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/27/lesson-learned-4-modifying-the-default-time-zone-for-your-local-time-zone/).

Also you can vote up this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/18739267-need-the-ability-to-set-a-time-zone-per-azure-sql), that feedback will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams.

Comment: Thanks @Jason for helping.