# How can I modify the time zone in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

Can you please tell me how to change the time zone in Azure SQL Database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the SQL Server (in Azure) TimeZone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051034/how-to-change-the-sql-server-in-azure-timezone)

Answer (score 5):

While you can't change the default time zone, Microsoft has provided mechanisms for dealing with time zones in your code within Azure. [Read this article.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2016/07/27/lesson-learned-4-modifying-the-default-time-zone-for-your-local-time-zone/)

Comment: [This](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/lesson-learned-4-modifying-the-default-time-zone-for-your-local/ba-p/368798#:~:text=select%20CONVERT(datetime%2C%20CONVERT(datetimeoffset%2C%20getdate())%20AT%20TIME%20ZONE%20%27Israel%20Standard%20Time%27)) is the best comment from that article: 
simply use the inline code: 

`select CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(datetimeoffset, getdate()) AT TIME ZONE 'Israel Standard Time')`